# Unzipping a .gz file to get a text file but getting a binary file?

Tags: files, compression, gzip, gunzip

I have a `.gz` file called `document.txt.gz` file. It is supposed to be a text file which got compressed to a gzip file. When I uncompress, I am getting a corrupt file.

I ran the following commands:

```
$ file document.txt.gz
```

and the result is

```
document.txt.gz: gzip compressed data, max speed, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)
```

and I again ran the file command on the unzipped portion

```
$ file document.txt.gz
```

and the result is

```
document.txt: gzip compressed data, last modified: Mon Mar 12 22:16:42 2018, from Unix
```

I am unsure why my uncompressed file is still a gzip compressed data.

Is there a way to retrieve the original file?

Comment: It looks to me that you run `file document.txt.gz` twice and get two different results. Could you please clarify what you are doing. Also, what does `gunzip document.txt.gz` say (if it does not create `document.txt`)?

Comment: Which command do you use to uncompress the file?

Answer (score 5):

In your case decompress the file by  `gzip -d document.txt.gz`
The -d flag is used to indicate the decompression or uncompression.

Read the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) page of gzip for more information.

Good luck!